# Is this a question that should be asked on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am trying to figure out which Stack Exchange site I should ask this question on:

> How can you build a borderless window that uses native window snap on Ubuntu?

I see three possibilities:

- **Ask Ubuntu:** I am considering this site because it is about Ubuntu, but I don't believe it is meant for programming questions like this.
- **Programmers** looks like a good choice, but I would prefer to have some code as a answer so that I can see what other people are doing about this. Programmers seems mostly a site for concepts, not for talking about actual code.
- **Stack Overflow** is also a good place for this question as it has to do with programming problems. However, Stack Overflow likes code in the question, and I can't give any because I have no clue how to go about this.

Where do you all think I should I place this question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like a programming question fit for Stack Overflow; however, you're right, adding in some code would help the question get positive votes.

I'm assuming you know how to generate a window, just any ole' window. If that's true, you could start with the code you used to generate that not-so-special window. Then ask what you need to do to *modify* the code. This way answerers already get an idea of what tools/SDK you have at your disposal, *and* they don't have to write code from scratch for you just to get to the point where they can then make whatever small change may be necessary to get from point A to point B.

Hope this helps!